# Windows "Documents and Settings" in another languages

Tags: windows, special-folders

My C# program traverse a drive for some data stored under user profile folder. I need to know whether some particular folder is "Documents and Settings". I cannot use SpecialFolders trick because I traverse not my system drive, but some attached drive, which may contain operating system in another language, for example, German.

What I need is simply a set of strings how "Documents and Settings" look like in localized Windows, e.g. German, Spanish, Chinese, Italian, Russian, Japanese, Korean, French and so on.

Is there any reference (file, link, etc) which may help me?

Comment: This is not solvable in general, because [the user may have customized the name of the Documents and Settings directory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722177%28v=WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: I'd like the same list!  While Raymond Chen is correct that the user could have changed it, for my purposes the out of the box list is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you may have to scan the directory structure and have your code make an educated guess as to the correct folder. Eg: look for soemthing that will be common to all localizations such as the hidden 'ntuser.dat' file.

To illustrate, type  'dir /a:h ntuser.dat /s' in a command prompt.

Comment: Thanks, lowlevel, that's a good idea! Will use it as one of empirics. However, I would still like to get some set of translations.

Comment: There is always someone who has to do something the hard way! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you need the Application Data folder equivalents the ones I know are:

```
German  (DE)   Application Data    Anwendungsdaten
Italian (IT)   Application Data    Dati applicazioni
Spanish (ES)   Application Data    Datos de programa
Polish  (PL)   Application Data    Dane aplikacji
```